# How to define application-specific default scopes with Doorkeeper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, doorkeeper

I am using doorkeeper for authorization with (trusted) mobile apps and remote webapps.

[There are options](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Using-Scopes) to:

- define default scopes to be used when the client does not provide a `scope` parameter (`default_scopes`)
- define additional scopes clients can request (`optional_scopes`)
- limit scopes that are allowed for each application (attribute `scopes` of each `Doorkeeper::Application` instance)

But is there a way to **define default scopes for each application *individually*?**

For *most* apps I want to provide only the bare minimum as default scopes, and everything else as additional options. *Some* legacy clients (old mobile app versions), however, need access to many scopes which they do not request explicitely. Is that possible?

Comment: Its covered in the section `Limiting scopes per Application` in the wiki page that you linked to. I think you're just thinking about it wrong. `default_scopes` it just for setting the default scopes when an application is created in doorkeeper or if the column is empty. Think of it like the default on a database column. To set the scopes per app you alter the database table - not the configuration.

Comment: @max So the `default_scopes` should not be relevant if the `scopes` column of the oauth application is populated? My oauth application instance is populated with "identity full_access" scopes, yet when I create a token without explicitely providing the `scope` parameter, the token is issued with only the "identity" scope, which matches my `default_scopes :identity` config... It seems like the `scopes` attribute of an application is meant as a whitelist to requestable scopes, not as a list of default scopes to be applied when the client does explicitely request one.